# Private ssh key deleted itself after attempted migration

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I'm migrating to a new laptop for work (Mac -> Mac, both on Sonoma). To migrate my ssh keys I made a tarball of my `~/.ssh` directory and copied it over to the new machine.

I went to ssh to one of my servers with my pubkey and ran into an error. It turns out that my ed25519 private key is now one byte (just an `N`). This happened on **both my new and my old machines**.

It only affected my ed25519 private key. The old rsa key is fine. I have other keys for application IDs that weren't affected, it's just my personal key.

Could it be a keychain issue? Part of a security policy? I'm at a loss here. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to transfer the file again, perhaps not as tarball?

Comment: "on both my new and my old machines" – Making a tarball should not modify any source file; extracting a tarball should result in identical files as the source files. Therefore I think most likely the file in question had been modified *earlier*.